# Добавление и изменение записей в таблице SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Здравствуйте! С помощью SQLAlchemy работаю с БД.
Создал вот такой класс:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class Pool(Base):
    """
    Управляет таблицей пулов. Создает, удаляет, возвращает список всех пулов в системе
    """
    __tablename__ = 'tbl_pool'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String(255), unique=True, nullable=False, default='default')
    description = Column(String(512))

    def __init__(self):
        self.session = BaseConnector.get_connection() # тут я получаю параметры подключения к базе

    def add_new_pool(self, pool_name='default_pool', pool_description="No description"):
        """
        Создает новую запись в таблице
        """
        self.name = pool_name
        self.description = pool_description
        try:
            self.session.add(self)
            self.session.commit()
        except IntegrityError:
            self.session.rollback()
            return 'Error! Poll exists'
        return 'Success! Poll created'

    def get_pool_list(self):
        """
        Получает список всех элементов в таблице
        """
        try:
            query_pool_list = self.session.query(Pool)
        except SQLAlchemyError:
            self.session.rollback()
            return {'error': 'error in query \"get_pool_list\"'}
        pool_dict = {}
        for pool in query_pool_list:
            pool_dict[pool.name] = pool.description
        return pool_dict
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как должен выглядеть метод, изменяющий поле `description` в зависимости от `id`, который будет передан как параметр (пример запроса: `UPDATE 'tbl_pool' SET description='new_description' WHERE id=10`)? Как должен выглядеть метод, делающий выборку (пример запроса: `SELECT description FROM 'tbl_pool' WHERE id=10`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить метод в Ваш класс, вот из документации по [update](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html)

```
def update_description(self, id_to_update, new_desc):
    try:
        query = self.session.query(Pool).filter(Pool.id == id_to_update).\
            update({Pool.description: new_desc}, synchronize_session=False)
        self.session.commit()
    except SQLAlchemyError:
        self.session.rollback()
        return {'error': 'error'}
    return True
```

Не уверен насколько правильно будет следующий подход с прямым присваиванием:

```
def update_description(self, id_to_update, new_desc):
    try:
        query = self.session.query(Pool).filter(Pool.id == id_to_update).first()
        query.description = new_desc
        self.session.commit()
    except SQLAlchemyError:
        self.session.rollback()
        return {'error': 'error'}
    return True
```

Comment: Приведенный Вами пример кода отрабатывает без ошибок.  Не уверен насчет "академичности" второго способа изменения данных, но он так же отрабатывает. Благодарю за помощь и указанную ссылку.